# Unorderable types in merge sort "int() <= list()"

Tags: python

This merge sort implementation fails on this error: " if (left_list[0] <= right_list[0]): TypeError: unorderable types: int() <= list()."

Why is right_list[0] considered to be a list instead of an int?

```
def merge_sort(array):

    def merge(left_list, right_list):

        result = []

        while len(left_list) > 0 or len(right_list) > 0:

            if len(left_list) > 0 and len(right_list) > 0:

                if (left_list[0] <= right_list[0]):

                    result.append(left_list[0])

                    left_list = left_list[1:]

                else:
                    result.append(right_list[0])

                    right_list = right_list[1:]



            elif len(left_list) > 0:

                result.append(left_list)
                left_list = left_list[1:]

            elif len(right_list) >  0:

                result.append(right_list[0])
                right_list = right_list[1:]

        return result

    if len(array) < 2:

        return array

    i_mid = len(array)//2

    left = array[:i_mid] 

    right = array[i_mid:]

    left = merge_sort(left)
    right = merge_sort(right) 

    result = merge(left, right)

    return result
```

Comment: Please provide us what data are you passing to the function, how you use it when the error happens.

Comment: you have a bug when the last element of your list is not the largest number when your list is an odd length, the last element ends up inside a list

Comment: Without knowing your input, it's hard to say exactly, but your error is most likely in `result.append(left_list)` - when you append `left_list` to `result` this way, the entire `left_list` becomes an element of `result`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bug: one branch was returning a list, when it should have been an item :) Fixed.

### source

```
def merge_sort(array):
    def merge(left_list, right_list):
        result = []
        while len(left_list) > 0 or len(right_list) > 0:
            if len(left_list) > 0 and len(right_list) > 0:
                if (left_list[0] <= right_list[0]):
                    result.append(left_list[0])
                    left_list = left_list[1:]
                else:
                    result.append(right_list[0])
                    right_list = right_list[1:]
            elif len(left_list) > 0:
                result.append(left_list[0]) # <==
                left_list = left_list[1:]
            elif len(right_list) >  0:
                result.append(right_list[0])
                right_list = right_list[1:]
        return result

    if len(array) < 2:
        return array

    i_mid = len(array)//2
    left = array[:i_mid] 
    right = array[i_mid:]
    left = merge_sort(left)
    right = merge_sort(right) 
    result = merge(left, right)
    return result

print merge_sort([5,4,3,1,2])
```

### output

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: +1, this was the problem. Thanks. The result list of my merge call had a list inside of it because of that typo.